# PropTypes for NextJS Image Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-proptypes, nextjs-image

I am including the new [Next.js Image component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) inside of another component like this:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Image from "next/image";

const Pattern = ({ classes, src, alt, width, height, layout }) => (
  <div className={classes.wrapper}>
    <Image
      src={src}
      alt={alt}
      width={width}
      height={height}
      layout={layout}
      className={classes.img}
    />
  </div>
);

Pattern.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({
    wrapper: PropTypes.string,
    img: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  src: PropTypes.string,
  alt: PropTypes.string,
  layout: PropTypes.string
};

export default Pattern;
```

As you see, we are using `prop-types`.  What I am having trouble figuring out is what prop type to set for width and height. Here is a sample usage of the Image component from the Next.js documentation:

```
<Image
  src="/me.png"
  alt="Picture of the author"
  width={500}
  height={500}
/>
```

I am not sure how to set this. `PropTypes.number`? `PropTypes.object`?  Something else?

Answer (score 1):

at your doc link if you scroll to required props it says it must be an integer, for `width` and/or `height`:

> The width of the image, in pixels. Must be an **integer** without a unit.

given that, `PropTypes.number` would be the correct PropTypes for both.

Answer (score 0):

try with string and isRequired

```
Pattern.propTypes = {
  width: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
}
```